# C# regex pattern don't work in own code but do in avalaible webtool for testing purpose

Tags: c#, regex, string

i guys heres is a piece of code i wrote.
i tested the regex pattern on different webtool,  they work in them!
 but in my C# code it doesn't, can you point me why?
 goal to achieve 
(IsMatch supposed to return true on every testing tool but not in this code it return false)

enter code here

```
 //not original code splitted is variable so i give it a static value for the question purpose
 var splitted = "\n/87238/he.james.lkjxzckj.jack.12357.asdasas.1231bfsg.wrew";

//original code
string final = "james-jack";

string finalRegex = "";

string[] regexSplit = final.Split(Convert.ToChar("-"));

finalRegex = String.Format(@"^(?=.*{0}).*$", String.Join(")(?=.*",regexSplit).ToLower());

Regex r = new Regex(finalRegex.ToLower(),RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 if (r.IsMatch(splitted.ToLower()))
 {
      //do something.....    
 }
```

Comment: why use `.ToLower()`? Whats the final string?

Comment: as said in the post splitted[0] is variable in this example i give it a static value but it could contains uppercase but if im correct with the regexOption.IgnorCase im not suppose to have to use it

Comment: The edited code works fine for me, the `r.IsMatch()` returns `true`.

Comment: well that the problemm on everything i tested it it return through but not in my app

Comment: what kind of information can i give you to help me?

Comment: Usually, when people say their regex does not work in C# and works online, they forget modifiers, `RegexOptions.Singleline` or `RegexOptions.Multiline`, or both. Since you do not provide any code that repros the issue, your question is off-topic for the time being.

Comment: i have edited splitted[0] example to be more real life scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Wiktor Stribiżew said, if you use `RegexOptions.Singleline` it will work. You have a new line in `splitted` variable, so your regex need to match multiple lines or you need to remove the new line `\n`

```
Regex r = new Regex(finalRegex.ToLower(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: `RegexOptions.MultiLine` will also work for the given example string. It depends on if you want to change the meaning of `.` or `^`.